# TemplateDoesNotExist at /payment/process/

Tags: django, django-templates, django-errors

My views, templates and urls are perfectly fine, but for some reason Django doesn't see process.html

Here is my file structure and the error

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCRod.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Wta.png)

I tried to change the file structure and the names of the templates multiple times, but no good outcome resulted

Answer (score 0):

please check if `payment` is in INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py

from the error trace you can see that apps `shop`, `cart` and `orders` appear in template search path but not `payment`.

see the Template-loader postmortem section of the error message